# Browserify and Vue: uncaught reference error: Vue is not defined

Tags: javascript, browserify

This is my first foray into any front-end development beyond basic jQuery stuff, and I'm using Vue.js along with some other packages with Browserify. My main 'app.js' looks like this:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap');
var moment = require('moment');
var fullCalendar = require('./vendor/fullcalendar.min.js');
var datetimepicker = require('./vendor/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js');
var select2 = require('./vendor/select2.min.js');
var VueResource = require('vue-resource');
var Vue = require('vue');
require('./videos/show.js');
require('./home.js');
require('./search.js');

Vue.use(VueResource);

new Vue({
    el: '#search',

    data: {
        message: 'Hello World!'
    },

});

...
```

It works as expected this way, but when I try to create a new Vue instance in another file (in search.js, for instance) I can't do  it. I get the 'Uncaught reference error: Vue is not defined' in my console. No problem with using the other required packages elsewhere - although I don't understand why I need to import jQuery the way I'm doing it... it won't work if I do:

```
var $, jQuery = require('jquery');
```

I'm sure this is something very basic and fundamental that I am not understanding yet but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you importing Vue into search.js just like the file above? With CommonJS, you do not want nor should use globals. You would require each dependency you have in each file.

Comment: I also see a lot of `require` calls without the thing being required being assigned to something -- I would expect to see `var x = require('x')`... That suggests to me you're using a lot of globals which again is a smell. It's one thing if it is for something like jQuery but for your own modules, it suggests some part of the concept isn't making sense. I'd suggest reading some more guides until it clicks.

Comment: Yeah I guess I am missing the basic concept. Before, I had a script on the login page that would use jstimezonedetect to get the user's timezone and store it in a hidden input that I would send to the server along with the user's credentials. Now, if I require that script, that function is called on every page load and the script tried to assign its return value to the $('#timezone') element. Doesn't make sense to me. All of my js operates on specific elements on specific pages. Do you have any recommendations on what to read to get up to speed?

Comment: Hrm... "The Secrets of the JavaScript Ninjas" is really good but I don't know if it would help that much for this specific case. You are almost there! For your issue with the hidden field -- make the module but don't run the code in the module -- the module can return a function and you would require that module where you need it like `var addHiddenField = require('./something');` and then use it like `addHiddenField()` only where you need it! Your modules should almost always return a value (ie `10`), a function or an object. Then you do something with the module after requiring it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is the basics of using modules. In general, a module should always export some behavior or property and then you require that module and use it. For example, say I wanted to add a hidden into to a form on some pages. I would do this:

AddSecretToken.js

```
module.exports = function(form) {
  // code here to add the hidden input to the passed in form
}
```

Then somewhere else where I had a form that needed the secret input, I would require it:

MyForm.js

```
var addSecretToken = require('./AddSecretToken');

...
// some code that makes a form
addSecretToken(myForm);
...
```

Obviously, at some point you need some code that actually runs something but that would be your root module or the page where you require the root module. So maybe you have an `app.js` at the top and it requires what it needs and then runs `app()` without exporting anything. That makes sense. But the majority of modules shouldn't be doing that.

Any time you need some behavior, you should make a module and then anywhere you need the behavior, you require the module. Each module should require what it depends on -- it shouldn't depend on any global (sometimes jQuery is an exception).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me! But in your example, where is MyForm.js included? Would it be required in my app.js? Is it also wrapped in the expression:  module.exports = function() { ... }

Comment: Yes, it would be included somewhere in app.js or in something that app.js requires (it could be far down the require tree if you think of the require tree as starting with the modules app.js requires). I suggest learning some NodeJS-style code even if you don't want to use NodeJS as a server because it shows the CommonJS pattern over and over.

Comment: Thanks again! Just starting to dig into node now. For my current project which uses Laravel on the back end (and its Blade templating system), I thought maybe this would be a good way to go since the majority of my js code is page-specific: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805308/sharing-common-code-across-pages-with-browserify .... do you think that is a good approach?